# How can I use sum with group by in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following many companies. Some of the companies have subjects and others do not. Something like this:

```
CompanyID  Subjects
1          2
2          4
3          1
4          0
```

I am trying to create a LINQ report that will give me this information. This is what I have so far. It correctly does an outer join so that even companies with no subjects are include in the list. Once I have that data then I group the date by company title. The problem is that the last select does not work correctly. Can someone suggest how I can get the sum. I was able to use count() but I need a sum as the way I have set things up is that when there are no subjects a value of 0 goes into Subjects and where there is 1 a value of one goes there. So by summing the count of Subjects at each break in the group I should be able to find out how many subjects are assigned to the company.

```
var test1 = from c in companies
            join s in subjects
              on "0000" + c.RowKey equals s.PartitionKey into outer
            from s in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            {
                Title = c.Title,
                Subjects = ((s == null) ? 0 : 1)
            } into split
            group split by split.Title into g
            select new
            {
                Title = g.Key,
                total = g.sum(s => s.Subjects)
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote the "sum" method without the capital "s". C# is case sensitive, so I think that's your problem, if you're getting a compile error.

Otherwise include the actual result of your query and what you expect, so we can compare it and try to find the problem.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks very much